# What is the pressure for A and B here?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

[image]

If there is a piston pushing down on the bigger branch, what do the pressures of B and A become? There are 3 scenarios I can think of and I'm not sure which one applies.

1. With Pascal's law, the pressures $P_A$ and $P_B$ are now $P_A + P_{piston}$ and $P_B + P_{piston}$, they are equal
2. Pascal law only applies on A because there is no atmospheric pressure there, $P_B$ is still $P_B$ and $P_A$ is $P_A + P_{piston}$
3. Pascal law only applies on B not sure why, $P_B$ is $P_B + P_{piston}$ and $P_A$ is still $P_A$

Answer (score 0):

I assume the system is in equilibrium and point A and the top of the piston are both exposed to the atmosphere. Let $h_A$ and $h_B$ be the elevations of points A and B, respectively.  Let $P_A$ and $P_B$ be the pressure at points A and B, respectively.  Since at equal elevations in the left and right sides the pressure is the same $$(1) P_A = P_B - \rho g(h_A - h_B)$$ where $\rho$ is the liquid density and $g$ is the acceleration of gravity. Also, $P_A = P_{atm}$ and $P_B = {F \over Area_b} + Mg + P_{atm}$ , where $P_{atm}$ is the atmospheric pressure, $F$ is the external force applied to the piston with area $Area_b$, and $M$ is the piston mass. So, we have $$(2) P_B - P_A = {F \over Area_b} + Mg$$ Using (1) in (2) we have $$(3)\rho g(h_A - h_B) = {F \over Area_b} + Mg$$